# Shapely .project() function not working on horizontal or vertical sections of line

Tags: python, shapely

I have a function called `intersect_point_to_line` that includes the following relevant code snippet:

```
for i in range(len(segment.coords[:])):
    if i < len(segment.coords)-1:
        seg = LineString([Point(segment.coords[i]),Point(segment.coords[i+1])])
        if seg.distance(point) <= d:
            intersect = seg.interpolate(seg.project(point))
```

This is designed to take a list of points that are slightly off of the line and snap a location that is used to write a new vertex that is on the line.

I have a very large list of points that I am running against a complex LineString that twists around quite a bit. The function works correctly except where the line goes vertical or horizontal. In those sections there is a short area where no points are snapped.

I am confident that the remainder of the code is correct. Am I missing something about the `.interpolate()` or `.project()` methods?

---

Edit: Here is the whole function

```
def intersect_point_to_line(segment, point, d):
    # iterate through each adjacent pair of points in the line segment
    for i in range(len(segment.coords[:])):
        if i < len(segment.coords)-1:
           seg=LineString([Point(segment.coords[i]),Point(segment.coords[i+1])])
            if seg.distance(point) <= d:
                intersect = seg.interpolate(seg.project(point))
                if not intersect.is_empty:
                    # calculate corrected distance to the actual point of intersection
                    real_dist = point.distance(intersect)
                    intX = intersect.coords[0][0]
                    intY = intersect.coords[0][1]
                    return (real_dist, intX, intY)
                else:
                    return False
```

The arguments are:
segment - a Shapely LineString of lat/lon pairs in Mercator 3785
point - a Shapely Point in Mercator 3785
d - a decimal value representing a threshold distance

This works for all points tested, except for where the LineString goes horizontal or vertical, for a distance of roughly 30 - 60 feet. I am attaching a representative screenshot below.

[image: Horizontal missing points]

Comment: Hello, the code snippet you provide cannot run as such. Could you add some sample values that exhibit the issue you have? and maybe figures of what you get versus what you expect.